# not able to save post model in mongodb atlas UI

Tags: node.js

> I have written all the necessary conditions to save the model but when i run the code, the model is not stored in the collections of mongo db atlas.
>   The code is like this

```js
post
  .save(function (err, newuser) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send("Username exists");
    } else {
      res.status(200).send("New User Created");
    }
  })
  .then((data) => {
    res.json(200, data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.json(400, { message: err });
  });
```

Comment: the starting line of the code should contain post.save(function(err,newuser){

Answer (score 0):

In else statement before sending the response you have to save the post using mongoose middleware Model.prototype.save(). For examples please visit 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-save . I hope this will be helpful.